# Why is the vector of pairs not storing the input?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have started to learn about C++11 STL. I use Kali Linux 2.0.
I have just written this simple code. But this is not giving the expected output. Seems like the vector v is not accepting the values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector< pair<int,int> > v(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int n1, n2;
        scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
        v.emplace_back(n1,n2);
        cout << v[i].first << " " << v[i].second << endl;
    }
}
```

Please, tell me where am I going wrong.
Everytime i enter some value to n1 and n2 in the loop, it gives the same output: 0 0. Why is v[i].first and second being evaluated to 0??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Inserts a new element at the end of the vector, right after its current last element."*  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/

You have pre-created n vector elements, so your new one is placed at n+i and the output of i is the default 0,0

Replace line

```
vector< pair<int,int> > v(n);
```

with

```
vector< pair<int,int> > v;
```

Live demo at 
http://cpp.sh/7umd

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector< pair<int,int> > v1( n );   // original code with pre-allocated defaule elements
    vector< pair<int,int> > v2;        // fixed code, no pre-creation of elements
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int n1, n2;
        scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
        v1.emplace_back(n1,n2);
        v2.emplace_back(n1,n2);
        cout << "v1 "<< v1[i].first << " " << v1[i].second << endl;
        cout << "v2 "<< v2[i].first << " " << v2[i].second << endl;

        cout << "v1 " << endl;
        for( auto p : v1 )
        {
            cout << p.first <<" " << p.second << endl;
        }
        cout << "v2 " << endl;
        for( auto p : v2 )
        {
            cout << p.first <<" " << p.second << endl;
        }
    }
}
```